# Difference between NetworkInfo.isRoaming() and TelephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming()

Tags: android, networking, roaming

I'm trying to detect wether the device is roaming or not in my app and I've found these two methods:

- [NetworkInfo.isRoaming()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isRoaming%28%29)
- [TelephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#isNetworkRoaming%28%29)

Is there an essential difference between them or can I just choose one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `TelephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming()`is 2G-related, whether `NetworkInfo.isRoaming()` is 3G-related - setting data-roaming on/off is a distinct option in the android-settings, so if it's off you still may get `true`for GSM (`TelephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming()`)

Comment: I'm not sure to get your answer. In my settings, I have only one check field ro allow on not Data Roaming. I've seen the field 'Use only 2G networks' but I don't really see the link with my question.

Comment: Sorry my answer might be a bit confusing. If the user is data roaming, that only mean he's using a service different from the one he applied to, right? 2G or 3G wouldn't make any difference then.

Comment: well, if you're outside your home country and you turn on the phone it will automatically establish a GSM connection to the roaming partner network -> `TelephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming()` will return `true`. If data roaming is disabled or 'use only 2g' is enabled `NetworkInfo.isRoaming()` will return `false`, because no data connection is established. If you switch data services on `NetworkInfo.isRoaming()` will return `true` as well, since now both (GSM and data connection) are established and in roaming mode

Comment: Ok I see now. That makes sense. Since I have no way to test that, I'm going to wait for a couple of hours to validate that answer. If someone could confirm this explanation, that would be great. Thanks!